# How do I tell Cmake where to find gfortran?

Tags: makefile, cmake, gfortran, macos-catalina

I've tried to install DAMASK for study but faced many problems with it. There's nobody at university to help me with these problems, so I'm lookin' for help here.

For installing and working, DAMASK requires Cmake with gcc and gfortran and many programmer things like PETSc, scipy and numpy. I successfully installed all of that using homebrew, but cmake cause trouble. It doesn't seem to find gcc and gfortran at default.

With gcc I used

`CC=/usr/bin/gcc`

and it worked.

But it doesn't working with FC, 'cause

`FC=/usr/bin/gfortran`
not working

even
`FC=/usr/local/cellar/gcc/10.2.0_4/bin/gfortran-10`
not working

ah, I'm using Macos Catalina and the code of the whole errors there:

```
MacBook-Pro-Andrej:DAMASK admin1$ make spectral
/var/folders/yb/bvc9yx0s2mx4yts18q2hfblw0000gp/T/tmp.XzJ43HLr/Makefile.petsc:4: /lib/petsc/conf/rules: No such file or directory
/var/folders/yb/bvc9yx0s2mx4yts18q2hfblw0000gp/T/tmp.XzJ43HLr/Makefile.petsc:5: /lib/petsc/conf/variables: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `/lib/petsc/conf/variables'.  Stop.
/var/folders/yb/bvc9yx0s2mx4yts18q2hfblw0000gp/T/tmp.XzJ43HLr/Makefile.petsc:4: /lib/petsc/conf/rules: No such file or directory
/var/folders/yb/bvc9yx0s2mx4yts18q2hfblw0000gp/T/tmp.XzJ43HLr/Makefile.petsc:5: /lib/petsc/conf/variables: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `/lib/petsc/conf/variables'.  Stop.
/var/folders/yb/bvc9yx0s2mx4yts18q2hfblw0000gp/T/tmp.XzJ43HLr/Makefile.petsc:4: /lib/petsc/conf/rules: No such file or directory
/var/folders/yb/bvc9yx0s2mx4yts18q2hfblw0000gp/T/tmp.XzJ43HLr/Makefile.petsc:5: /lib/petsc/conf/variables: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `/lib/petsc/conf/variables'.  Stop.
/var/folders/yb/bvc9yx0s2mx4yts18q2hfblw0000gp/T/tmp.XzJ43HLr/Makefile.petsc:4: /lib/petsc/conf/rules: No such file or directory
/var/folders/yb/bvc9yx0s2mx4yts18q2hfblw0000gp/T/tmp.XzJ43HLr/Makefile.petsc:5: /lib/petsc/conf/variables: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `/lib/petsc/conf/variables'.  Stop.
/var/folders/yb/bvc9yx0s2mx4yts18q2hfblw0000gp/T/tmp.XzJ43HLr/Makefile.petsc:4: /lib/petsc/conf/rules: No such file or directory
/var/folders/yb/bvc9yx0s2mx4yts18q2hfblw0000gp/T/tmp.XzJ43HLr/Makefile.petsc:5: /lib/petsc/conf/variables: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `/lib/petsc/conf/variables'.  Stop.
Found PETSC_DIR:


Found PETSC_INCLUDES:


Found PETSC_EXTERNAL_LIB:


Found PETSC_LINKER:


Found MPI Fortran Compiler:


Found MPI C Compiler:


-- The Fortran compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:109 (project):
  No CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER could be found.

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "FC" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER to the full
  path to the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/Users/admin1/DAMASK/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/Users/admin1/DAMASK/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
make: *** [build/spectral] Error 1
```

I don't know anything in UNIX programming but I was told to do it if I want to write my
thesis and my diploma...

So I'm lookin' for help here...

Comment: did you try to put it in your path environment variable?

Comment: Have you tried the cmake flag `CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER` (n.b. this is case sensitive) ?

Comment: I'm so sorry, but I don't know how to do that... Even after I googled this solutions, I understand nothing... I can take some code and thy it, I don't know how to work with this real coding case...
But I read about PATH variable and in my case it looks not as in internet...
About flags, I understand nothing... I don't know how to open Cmake itself 'cause I don't need it without DAMASK and it used as an helper to run the program...
That's the only thing I know about that...

Comment: Do you do `export FC`? Generally, you should read up a bit about shell and `make`.

Comment: Yup, I did export FC and nothing changed so I guess the problem is in compiler itself or something completely different. I tried to use intel compiler (ifort) but it did nothing new... Anyone know where I can find right file of gfortran after installation ( ‘cause I think that I’m picking wrong folder with wrong file)

Comment: I figured out how to put in path environment variable and cmake flags, but the thing is that nothing works anyway.... Will be glad to hear other ideas. Oh, and by the way I reinstalled gfortran and now I'm sure that I'm picking the correct file.